# Can two private keys generate the same (public) Bitcoin address?

Tags: address, client, address-generation, key-collision

I know that private key is generated randomly by wallet. Is it possible that wallet generate the same address which is used in Bitcoin?

In other words:
Given two private keys k<sub>a</sub> ≠ k<sub>b</sub>, is it possible that they both generate the same public Bitcoin address?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes,** you can have two keys generate the *same address*.

There are 2^160 possible addresses, and 2^256 possible private keys, so each address corresponds to roughly 2^(256-160)=2^96 private keys. Any of these will generate the same address and thus be able to spend the money owned by that address. Since 2^160 is so large, however, it would take a near-eternity to find any collisions.

Whether two private keys can generate the *same public key* is another question. I think the answer is yes, but I am not sure on that. The public key in uncompressed form consists of two 256-bit numbers, which are X and Y coordinates on an elliptic curve. However, the [compressed form](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=316350.0) is just the X coordinate [plus a bit](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm), from which you can calculate the whole public key. This means the space is (at most) 2^257. Unless there is a one-to-one mapping due to the mathematical properties of the cryptography used, each compressed public key corresponds to roughly 0.5 private keys (with the same distribution you'd get from picking a random number from 1 to 2^257, 2^256 times), so some private keys will collide, while others will not.

*Actually finding* any pair of different private keys that generate the same public key or address would be quite difficult. Either it would involve a huge amount of computation and/or luck, or it would be due to finding a serious vulnerability in the algorithm(s) used.

Comment: And if such a collision is found and two private keys with the same address exist, does that mean that both keys can be used to spend the money ?

Comment: Yes and no. Both keys can be used to spend tx outputs in pay-to-pubkey-hash format (the most common). But if the tx output is in pay-to-pubkey format, then only the private key corresponding to the pubkey can redeem it.

Comment: @André Yep. It would have a good deal of notoriety if anyone noticed two signatures with different public keys for the same address in the blockchain. And to uminatsu: you're right, if there is a one-to-one mapping of private to public keys. In any case, paying to a pubkey hash gives you 256 bits of security instead of 160 (both are fine for real-world use, so the shorter is nicer for saving space)

Answer (score 2):

private keys above the group order have the same addresses as the keys starting at 0.

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141  1MsHWS1BnwMc3tLE8G35UXsS58fKipzB7a
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364142  1EHNa6Q4Jz2uvNExL497mE43ikXhwF6kZm
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364143  1LagHJk2FyCV2VzrNHVqg3gYG4TSYwDV4m
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364144  1NZUP3JAc9JkmbvmoTv7nVgZGtyJjirKV1
```

...

```
000000000000000000000000000000014551231950b75fc4402da1732fc9bebb fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffc  1HtRa3HaTfX4eDrTzkZWfnLD9cZAyhMDEd
000000000000000000000000000000014551231950b75fc4402da1732fc9bebc fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffd  1FvN1jJU6kQCub9nQFuJhdfixpBdngxLme
000000000000000000000000000000014551231950b75fc4402da1732fc9bebd fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffe  1JHzdjEL4xQ7yifAaQQKAfqPyAN92vfstP
000000000000000000000000000000014551231950b75fc4402da1732fc9bebe ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff  12M4QznuNZH2BRVbLK8SKvNqGTPJpCpST7
```

Comment: The ones larger than the group order are invalid though, something must be doing `mod n` on the numbers to make a pubkey out of them.